# Change pace in Slider JavaFx possible?

Tags: slider, javafx-2

Maybe, im just blind but i got an slider and i need to know if there is any way to change the paces.

Example:
Slider from 7.5 to 13.0 
Pace 0.5

When i set the value in the label, i would like to have something like this:
7.5;
8.0;
8.5

For every movement with the slider i get something like this at this moment:
7.5;
7.51

Tried everything. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Set the tick unit for the slider and snap it's value to the ticks.

For the sample values you give in your question:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
...
Slider slider = new Slider(7.5, 13, 7.5);
slider.setMajorTickUnit(0.5);
slider.setMinorTickCount(0);
slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

From the [Slider setSnapToTicks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setSnapToTicks%28boolean%29) javadoc:

> Indicates whether the value of the Slider should always be aligned with the tick marks. This is honored even if the tick marks are not shown.

Comment: More correctly, code snippet should look like this :         Slider slider = new Slider(7.5, 13, 7.5);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(0.5);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(0);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);, and the major call here - slider.setMinorTickCount(0), because otherwise, there are 5 minor ticks between each pair of major ticks by default, and snapping will be done to the nearest minor tick, not the major one.

Comment: Updated answer to also set the minor tick count to 0 so snapping works as expected.  Thanks Alexander.

Comment: Awesome! First i thought it looks like it doesnt work, but i just overlooked the snapping.

Looks very elegant :) 
Additionally, i add a ArrayList with the values the label has to show.